# Do you know any way of configuring cloud run to set a cloudsql from a cloudbuild.yaml?

Tags: google-cloud-run

I'm trying to connect a cloudsql instance to a cloud run service in a safer way than setting the postgres db to be public: to do so, [1][I read it can be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56818335/gcloud-beta-run-deploy-fails-after-sucessfully-uploading-image-fails-to-enable) through the CLI, but isn't it better managing the configuration using files rather than commands? Because, in this case, I will have to update the image every time the cloud build trigger build it, isn't it? So' I'm thinking on including `--set-cloudsql-instances` in the cloudbuild.yaml with the following code, but after running the logs say this `--set-cloudsql-instances INSTANCE_NAME` is an invalid argument. Can you give me any advice on setting this?

Thanks in advance.

```
gcloud beta run deploy $PROJECT --image $IMAGE_NAME --platform=managed --region us-central1 --project $PROJECT --set-cloudsql-instances $PROJECT-db
```

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - build
      - '--no-cache'
      - '-t'
      - '$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - .
      - '-f'
      - Dockerfile
    id: Build
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - push
      - '$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
    id: Push
  - name: gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk
    args:
      - run
      - services
      - update
      - $_SERVICE_NAME
      - '--platform=managed'
      - '--image=$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - >-
        --labels=managed-by=gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run,commit-sha=$COMMIT_SHA,gcb-build-id=$BUILD_ID,gcb-trigger-id=$_TRIGGER_ID,$_LABELS
      - '--region=$_DEPLOY_REGION'
      - '--quiet'
      - '--set-cloudsql-instances $PROJECT_ID:$_DEPLOY_REGION:INSTANCE_NAME'
    id: Deploy
    entrypoint: gcloud
images:
  - '$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
options:
  substitutionOption: ALLOW_LOOSE
substitutions:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an equal and you need to define the `INSTANCE_NAME` variable in your Cloudbuild (I noted it as substitution variable `$_INSTANCE_NAME`)

```
- '--set-cloudsql-instances=$PROJECT_ID:$_DEPLOY_REGION:$_INSTANCE_NAME'
```

Comment: Thank you so much Guillaume!